# code for batch crop picture in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I wrote a macro to batch crop and resize the pictures in selected slides, the resize work good, but after I added the crop codes, it is not working. Please see the codes as below, is there any thing wrong? welcome and thanks suggestion.

```
Sub crpicture ()
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape

For Each osld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
For Each oshp In osld.Shapes

 oshp.PictureFormat.CropLeft = 0
 oshp.PictureFormat.CropTop = 0.5 * 72
 oshp.PictureFormat.CropRight = oshp.Width - oshp.Height
 oshp.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 0

 oshp.Height = 3 * 72
 oshp.Left = 3.4 * 72
 oshp.Top = 0.7 * 72
 oshp.ZOrder msoSendToBack

      Next
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: "It's not working" means what *exactly* - best not to make us guess if you know what the problem is...

Comment: can not run ask to debug. oshp.PictureFormat.CropLeft = 0
     oshp.PictureFormat.CropTop = 0.5 * 72
     oshp.PictureFormat.CropRight = oshp.Width - oshp.Height
     oshp.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 0 shows yellow,  I do not know where and why these codes wrong

Comment: Shapes only have a `PictureFormat` if they are a picture or an OLEObject:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745665.aspx  If there are shapes on your slides which aren't either of those two then you'll need to test for that.  What's the error message/number you get?

Comment: I fixed the problem. thanks